# Typing closing brace in javascript auto formats the block in K&R style

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

When I have the following javascript code in VS 2017, using Resharper 2019.2.2

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sections.length; i++)
{
```

and I type the closing brace, I get

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sections.length; i++) {
}
```

despite my efforts to disable auto formatting and K&R style indentation.

Why?

Here comes my settings

## Visual studio is setup to not auto format on closing brace

[image: Screenshot]

## Visual studio is setup to have an opening brace on a new line

[image: Screenshot]

## Resharper is setup to use BSD style brace indentation

[image: Screenshot]

## Resharper is setup to not auto format on closing brace

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the exact version of Visual Studio? You can see it in `Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio`.

Comment: Do you have other extensions installed?

Comment: Visual studio 2017, there is a tag in the posting @SzabolcsDézsi

Comment: Customize Visual Studio Window Title, Cloud Explorer for VS 2017, Editor Guidelines, Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools, Developer Analytics Tools, Microsoft Library Manager, Razor Language Services, Visual F# Tools, Dotnet Extensions for Test Explorer, Microsoft Visual Studio Test Platform, Roslyn Expression Evaluators, Roslyn Interactive Components, Roslyn Language Services @DmitryOsinovskiy

Comment: You need to find out who is to blame. Try to disable ReSharper: Tools>Options>ReSharper...>Suspend Now. Would the problem go away? Also, IIRC there is another JavaScript engine in VS 2017. Look for another JavaScript node in Tools>Options>Text Editor and ensure that you have correct formatting options there.

Comment: @AndersLindén That's not the exact version... Anyways, try to update to a later VS2017. Maybe there's a bug in the one you're using: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/256343/javascript-place-open-brace-on-new-line-doesnt-wor.html

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.17. It is according to the "Checkf for Updates" dialog "up to date"